# Error when dowloading/reading the files from share point document libraries

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, csom, download

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ClientContext
>   context, tring serverRelativeUrl)    at
>   SPConsoleClientModelDemo.Program.GetFoldersAndFiles1(Folder
>   mainFolder, C*emphasized text*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;


namespace SPConsoleClientModelDemo
{
    class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        try
        {
            string SharepointURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharepointURL"];
            string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
            string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password.ToCharArray())
                passWord.AppendChar(c);
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SharepointURL);
            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passWord);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Lists);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Mydocumentlibrary");
            clientContext.Load(list);             
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("" + list.RootFolder.Name.ToString());
          //  GetFoldersAndFiles11(list.RootFolder, clientContext);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n\n\n" + ex.Source);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to download all the folders and files from share point site  to my network drive. but when I call GetFoldersAndFiles1 method i am getting the above error at two lines in the above code 
 first line  is   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  and second one is var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
       and the error message is The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: that is my complete code (i am trying to get all the folders and files from my document library

Comment: Use below code to get the files from the folder: cxt.Load(list.RootFolder);
        cxt.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        cxt.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
        cxt.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
        List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
        foreach(Folder f in fcol)
        {
            if (f.Name == "filename")
            {
                cxt.Load(f.Files);
                cxt.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                foreach (File file in fileCol)
                {}

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , i am getting this error before i go to files in the root folder in the above example  clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); appeared multiple places but getting the error in anyone of the line of (executequery) and that the error is not regular (i.e intermittent)